# Can't figure out where a value is being set

Tags: c#

I'm working on some Project Euler questions and need some help understanding a solution I found.

My question is: Where the heck is X being set in the SkipWhile method call?? When I break the code during runtime and step through to that point I never see a value being set for it.  Yet the code will work all the way through.  I checked the definition for SkipWhile and maybe I just don't understand how the arguments being passed in the call satisfy the 3 parameter method definition. Same thing for Math.Pow - Where is that X getting set!?

```
public long FindGreatestPrimeFactor(long factorGreaterThan, long number)
    {
        long upperBound = (long)Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(number));

        // find next factor of number
        long nextFactor = Range(factorGreaterThan + 1, upperBound)
             .SkipWhile(x => number % x > 0).FirstOrDefault();

        // if no other factor was found, then the number must be prime
        if (nextFactor == 0)
        {
            return number;
        }
        else
        {
            // find the multiplicity of the factor
            long multiplicity = Enumerable.Range(1, Int32.MaxValue)
                 .TakeWhile(x => number % (long)Math.Pow(nextFactor, x) == 0)
                 .Last();

            long quotient = number / (long)Math.Pow(nextFactor, multiplicity);

            if (quotient == 1)
            {
                return nextFactor;
            }
            else
            {
                return FindGreatestPrimeFactor(nextFactor, quotient);
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<long> Range(long first, long last)
    {
        for (long i = first; i <= last; i++)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are talking about the [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx):

```
x => number % x > 0
```

> All lambda expressions use the lambda operator =>, which is read as "goes to". The left side of the lambda operator specifies the input parameters (if any) and the right side holds the expression or statement block.

In a LINQ expression, each item, when iterated over, is supplied to the lambda. In the body of the lambda, if you wish to refer to the item, you need to give it a name. In this case the parameter ends up named `x`.

Comment: So what exactly would be X's value in that line Oded?  I think I'm stuck conceptually as I'm reading it like this: X is set to number then, x mod itself has to be greater than 0.

Comment: @user178471 - `Range` returns a _list_ of `long`. When you iterate over the list, you supply one `long` at a time to the lambda to be processed by the function (right side of the `=>`).

Comment: @user178471 - [From delegates to lambdas](http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/39674/0/page/1) may be of help in understanding what lambdas are.

Comment: So Oded, when I look at the definition of SkipWhile in the Enumerable .NET namespace here is what I find: 
public static IEnumerable<TSource> SkipWhile<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate);
Is X satisfying source, and number % x > 0 satisfying predicate?  I'm going to read through that link you gave me on lamdas and delegates right now.

Comment: @user178471 - not the `this` keyword before `IEnumerable<TSource>` - that signifies an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) on the generic `IEnumerable<T>` interface. The important bit is the `Func<TSource, bool>` - that's a delegate that takes the generic type `TSource` (`long` in this case) and returns a `bool`. That's the delegate (think anonymous function) that executes per item in the list.

Comment: Ahhhh, it's all coming together.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The expressions that look like this:

```
x => number % x > 0
```

are called [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). They actually are functions, and `x` is a parameter. `SkipWhile` takes a function, and then executes it with different values for its parameters.

Here is how the lambda expression would be written as a function:

```
bool Foobar(long x)
{
    return number % x > 0;
}
```

In `SkipWhile`, I believe the function is called with `x` being the first item in the list. If it is true, the function is called again with the second item in the list, and so on down until the function returns false.

In this case, `SkipWhile` is asking for a function that will convert a value of the type in the list to a `bool`. Lambda expressions are a concise way to express this.

Answer (score 0):

`SkipWhile` is retrieving its input values (the `x`) from the `Range` method, which in turn returns numbers from `factorGreaterThan + 1` up to `upperBound`. Not sure why the author decided to write a method for this, since this is built in with the `Enumerable.Range` method.

Comment: The built in `EnumerableRange` works with `int`, not `long` - perhaps that's the reason.